# Open HashTag page with native Facebook-App

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to open the HashTag-Page with the native facebook app.

This code works fine when opening profiles:

```
String facebookScheme = "fb://profile/" + facebookId;
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookScheme)); 
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

But how to open HashTags like this?

https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/audi